# Redshift External Table all fields are empty

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, external, aws-glue

My external table (s3) mounted in Redshift. Redshift shows rows, columns but all the fields in all of the records are empty!

```
drop table if exists external_schema_name.table_name;
create external table external_schema_name.table_name (
(dml stuff snipped)
) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe' 
  WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'ignore.malformed.json' = 'true',
  'paths'='$.properties,$.ratings') 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
location 's3://mybucket/events_raw/table_name/' 
TABLE PROPERTIES (
  'CrawlerSchemaDeserializerVersion'='1.0', 
  'CrawlerSchemaSerializerVersion'='1.0',  
  'classification'='json', 
  'json.schema.resolution'='position',
  'compressionType'='gzip',
  'serialization.null.format'='')
;
```

Here is what it returns:

```
select count(*) from  external_schema_name.table_name;
  count   
----------
 10256551
(1 row)
select distinct_id from external_schema_name.table_name limit 2;
 distinct_id 
-------------
 (2 rows)
select distinct_id from external_schema_name.table_name where distinct_id is not null limit 2;
 distinct_id 
-------------
(0 rows)
```

Comment: Are you saying that the middle query did not show any results (even though it claimed `2 rows`)? Or did you remove the output from the Question? What happens if you `SELECT * FROM external_schema_name.table_name LIMIT 2`?

Comment: @Lt Dan: I hope I didn't overlook something. What is shown looks perfectly fine. Guess the problem is with something not shown.  I for one cannot see the problem.  Maybe can you just do the same thing with same small fake data and post input and output.  Should be simple to create a bucket with small fake data that shows the problem?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein : all fields in the records are "blank", even when selecting a limited number of rows by an offset of 100's, or 1,000's of rows.

Comment: @kai "Guess the problem is with something not shown." YES! That IS the problem!  ;-)
Those fields should have letters and numbers and stuff displayed in them, but they don't. AWS Redshift can count the rows, and the columns, but it is not displaying the values stored in each field.

Comment: I would suggest starting with the basics. How are you querying the information (what program are you using, what computer is it on, etc)? Try creating a sample table from the [Creating external tables for Amazon Redshift Spectrum - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-spectrum-external-tables.html) documentation just to confirm that queries are working correctly. If that is working, create a small sample file containing your data, put it in a new location in S3 and try creating the External Table to use that data. Your goal is to `SELECT *` and see the data.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein  Small tables work fine. Big tables that span multiple files do not.